# How to overlay multiple plots of same function with .NET line charts, without .NET drawing lines between all points

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, mschart

Is there some  .Series() setting to inhibit this?

I want to overlay (ie. superimpose) subsequent (ie. multiple) complex sample plots to see any unexpected variance between samples.  For example, each plot is a sine wave, with 32 angle points along the X-axis, and the Y-axis is the sine of X-axis angle.

For each subsequent plot, starting at angle-0  a line is drawn from point at angle-0 all the way back over to the point at the last angle.

(The plot looks like something from an ancient 1960's toy called "Spirograph."  In other words, instead of a line graph that is a single line with a beginning and an end, the there is an unwanted line drawn from the last (right-most) point back to the first (left-most) point.)  The Spirograph allusion seems lost on Taw below, who responded as if a Spirograph is what I wanted in the first place.

```
Me.Chart_antenna_window.Series("sample_point_I").Points.AddXY( scan_package_index, simulation_value_I)
Me.Chart_antenna_window.Series("sample_point_Q").Points.AddXY( scan_package_index, simulation_value_Q)
```

The only method I can think of is to add to the Chart a new Series for every new plot.

Comment: An image or sketch of what you want could be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is not very clear; but a Spirograph-like result can be created indeed by adding a number of series..

Spirograph chart result:

[image]

The example uses the `Polar` chart type; it has `n` points around the circle.
It creates half the number of series and makes the steps larger for each.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];

    chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = false;

    int n = (int) numericUpDown1.Value;  // 32 for the above image

    ca.AxisX.Maximum = n ;

    ca.AxisX.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
    ca.AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
    ca.AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
    ca.AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;

    for (int j = 1; j < n / 2; j++)
    {
        Series s = chart1.Series.Add("S" + j);
        s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Polar;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            s.Points.AddXY(i * j , 100);
        }
    }

}
```

We can use other numbers:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1_Click(null, null);
}
```

Let's look at a few results..:

[image]

**Update:** The above code is very simple, indeed simplistic, in other words: it is not always right. In fact it only works for prime numbers. For other numbers some series will wrap over themselves and miss points. Code to correct this is a bit more involved..