# Combining contour and scatter plot in C# plotting library

Tags: c#, plot, contour, scatter

Is there any free plotting C# library capable to combine a contour and scatter plot. I want to replicate the following example in python.

Thanks

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')

def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) ** 10 + np.cos(10 + y * x) * np.cos(x)
    
x = np.linspace(0, 5, 50)
y = np.linspace(0, 5, 40)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)

contours = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, 3, colors='black')
plt.clabel(contours, inline=True, fontsize=8)
plt.imshow(Z, extent=[0, 5, 0, 5], origin='lower', cmap='RdGy', alpha=0.5)
plt.colorbar()
plt.scatter([1, 2, 2], [2, 3, 0.5], s=50)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You want to add a Series to the existing contour plots containing scatter points.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51828558/how-to-overlay-multiple-plots-of-same-function-with-net-line-charts-without-n

Comment: My question is related to the library and not how to implement this. I'm already aware how to achieve this by adding a new series of data. But which library is capable to do this?

Comment: The Net library.  Why use a 3rd party library when Net already does what you want?

Comment: Could you please share a minimum working example for this plot using the native .NET library as you mentioned? Thanks.

Comment: It is in the link : Series s = chart1.Series.Add("S" + j);